# Technique for creating unique custom CMS page ID's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, content-management-system

I have a website where users can upload blog posts. This website is built entirely by me, no framework documentation to look through.

I've been using Mysql's Primary key as the page ID in the url, but i don't like this as it gives away too much information to the user. 
The id appears somewhat like this

```
www.website.com/view?post=97
```

Youtube uses an 11 letter combination and looks somewhat like

```
watch?v=wEoFhRCUEs8 // *Not a plug*
```

I was thinking of encrypting the ID in an MD5, but  1) this is far too long, 2) Not the intended use of MD5.

Any ideas on how sites like facebook, stackoverflow, youtube etc encrypt each ID whilst ensuring that it is unique?

I'm also unsure if it is best to save a secondary unique ID in mysql, or just parse it through a function that converts it every time I need it.

Thanks

Comment: Why not make use of [`uniqid()`](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you the logic:

first there is a post //
then it is tried to be inserted into the database //
Before inserting into the database //
Generate a random string //
As soon as you generate the random string, check in the database if it is taken //
if it is taken, generate a new string //
else utilize that string //
now insert all the necessary data into the database //
Done //

Answer (score 0):

You are actually on the right track with MD5.  Basically what you need to do is create a simple encyption based on the post id.  As long as it is not security related I'd write a quick 2 way hashing algorithm that allows you to convert 97 to "wEoFhRCUEs8" and vice versa.  That way you can look up posts later.

Probably something that just bit shifts the number and xors it into a "secret" string.. etc...

If you want to go a little more secure try the mcrypt lib, depending on algorithm you can limit the output size.

If you don't do a reversable encryption then you have no choice but to store your unique string with your post so you can look it up later.